# iPad App mirroring - TV out

Tags: ipad, output, television, airdrop

I have a View : which plays video . 
On view we can able to add image / Text above video layer .

Now we would like to show view with video playing on TV output .

I have used External Display Class ,Is there any way to get desired output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Multiple Display Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html) by Apple. You will need to listen for `UIScreenDidConnectNotification` notifications and create a new `UIWindow` instance with your content to attach to the new `UIScreen`.

You may also find the [AirPlay for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/airplay/) page helpful, particularly the WWDC videos.

Edit: if you are looking for a way to programmatically enable mirroring, this is not allowed by Apple. You will need to direct your users to bring up the [system bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+airplay+mirroring&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_kzhU9qkKuLKsQSL0YL4DA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1680&bih=952) and toggle in on their own.